# Воспроизвести звук на сайте

Tags: аудио, javascript

Все мы пользователи соц. сети. На примере вконтакте: при получении сообщения мы слышим характерный звук - щелчок.

Мне оч. понравилась эта идея и я хочу в купе с уведомлениями также воспроизводить файл.

Как это можно сделать кроссбраузерно на js?

Можно ли что-нибудь выжать хорошее из http://vkontakte.ru/js/sound.js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**SoundManager 2**](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) — прекрасное решение!

[**Примеры**](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/) данного решения.

---

Как дополнил **[[@org](/users/2294/org)](/users/2294/org)**, вот [**здесь**](http://www.free-lance.ru/projects/?pid=708379) можно найти большое количество разных звуков.

Comment: Ну добавлю к хорошему ответу ссылочку где можно скачать звуки: 
http://www.free-lance.ru/projects/?pid=708379

Answer (score 0):

> Все мы пользователи соц. сети.

Ой, не надо за всех :-)
А проблема звуковых уведомлений в уэб-интерфейсах исчерпала себя с появлением элемента [`<audio>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#audio). До того действительно, приходилось делать городить составные решения с апплетом. См. [Fallback options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Fallback_options).

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно воспользоваться плагином [Ion.Sound](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/index.html)

Вот [несколько примеров](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.sound/demo.html) использования.